# PyQt4 Scrapy Implementation

Tags: python, scrapy, pyqt4

Using scrapy I faced a problem of javascript rendered pages. For the site Forum Franchise for example the link http://www.idee-franchise.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=69, trying to scrap the source html I couldn't retrieve any posts because they seem to be "appended" after the page is being rendered (Probably through javascript).

So i was looking on the net for a solution to this problem, and i came across https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/ultimate-guide-for-scraping-javascript-rendered-web-pages/ .

I am completely new to PYPQ, but was hoping to take a shortcut and copy paste some code.

This worked perfectly for when i tried to scrap a single page. But then when i implemented this in scrapy i get the following error :

```
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::configurationAdded(QNetworkConfiguration) to QNetworkConfigurationManager::configurationAdded(QNetworkConfiguration)
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::configurationRemoved(QNetworkConfiguration) to QNetworkConfigurationManager::configurationRemoved(QNetworkConfiguration)
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::configurationChanged(QNetworkConfiguration) to QNetworkConfigurationManager::configurationChanged(QNetworkConfiguration)
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::onlineStateChanged(bool) to QNetworkConfigurationManager::onlineStateChanged(bool)
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::configurationUpdateComplete() to QNetworkConfigurationManager::updateCompleted()
```

If i scrap a single page, then no error occurs, but when i set crawler to recursive mode, then right at the second link i get an error that python.exe stopped working and the above error.

I will searching for what this could be, and somewhere i read a QApplication object should only be initiated once.

Could someone please tell me what should be the proper implementation?

The Spider

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import sys, traceback
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from crawler.items import ThreadItem, PostItem
from crawler.utils import utils


class IdeefranchiseSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "ideefranchise"
    allowed_domains = ["idee-franchise.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.idee-franchise.com/forum/',
        # 'http://www.idee-franchise.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=69',
    )

    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='/forum/'), callback='parse_thread', follow=True)
    ]

    def parse_thread(self, response):
        print "Parsing Thread", response.url
        thread = ThreadItem()
        thread['url'] = response.url
        thread['domain'] = self.allowed_domains[0]
        thread['title'] = self.get_thread_title(response)
        thread['forumname'] = self.get_thread_forum_name(response)
        thread['posts'] = self.get_thread_posts(response)
        yield thread

        # paginate if possible
        next_page = response.css('fieldset.display-options > a::attr("href")')
        if next_page:
            url = response.urljoin(next_page[0].extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_thread)

    def get_thread_posts(self, response):
        # using PYQTRenderor to reload page. I think this is where the problem
        # occurs, when i initiate the PYQTPageRenderor object. 
        soup = bs(unicode(utils.PYQTPageRenderor(response.url).get_html()))

        # sleep so that PYQT can render page
        # time.sleep(5)

        # comments
        posts = []
        for item in soup.select("div.post.bg2") + soup.select("div.post.bg1"):
            try:
                post = PostItem()
                post['profile'] = item.select("p.author > strong > a")[0].get_text()
                details = item.select('dl.postprofile > dd')
                post['date'] = details[2].get_text()
                post['content'] = item.select('div.content')[0].get_text()

                # appending the comment
                posts.append(post)
            except:
                e = sys.exc_info()[0]
                self.logger.critical("ERROR GET_THREAD_POSTS %s", e)
                traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
        return posts
```

The PYPQ implementation

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage 

class Render(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()
        self.app.quit()


class PYQTPageRenderor(object):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url

    def get_html(self):
        r = Render(self.url)
        return unicode(r.frame.toHtml())
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper implementation, if you want to do it yourself, would be to create a [downlader middleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#writing-your-own-downloader-middleware) that uses PyQt to process a request. It will be instantiated once by Scrapy.

Should not be that complicated, just

1. Create QTDownloader class in the `middleware.py` file of your project
2. The constructor should create the `QApplication` object.
3. The `process_request` method should do the url loading, and HTML fetching. Note that you return a [Response](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response) object with the HTML string.
4. You might do appropriate clean-up in a `_cleanup` method of your class.
5. Finally, activate your middleware by adding it to the `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES` variable of the `settings.py` file of your project.

If you don't want to write your own solution, you could use an existing middleware that uses Selenium to do the downloading, like [scrapy-webdriver](https://github.com/brandicted/scrapy-webdriver). If you don't want to have a visible browser, you can instruct it to use PhantomJS.

EDIT1: 
So the *proper* way to do it, as pointed out by [Rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1901546/rejected) is to use a download handler. The idea is similar, but the downloading should happen in a `download_request` method, and it should be enabled by adding it to `DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS`. Take a look to the [WebdriverDownloadHandler](https://github.com/brandicted/scrapy-webdriver/blob/master/scrapy_webdriver/download.py#L16) for an example.

Comment: thank you for the guidelines. i will try it out right away

Comment: I've always considered this a poor implementation.  A middleware should not be what handles doing the downloading.  You're shortcutting the downloader, which will have a lot of un-intended results (like throttling/delays).  The *proper* way to directly implement it would be to re-write the http(s) download handler.

Comment: @Rejected I can't seem to find documentation on Downloaders. Could you please tell me what should i be reading for Downloaders? Thank you